# Help with calculating frequency offset

Tags: oscillator, frequency, offset, gnss, satellite

A 10 MHz TXCO is driving a receiver’s front end and has a frequency deviation of 10 ppm.  It drives a direct downconversion RF front-end mixing the L5 frequency.  What is the frequency offset at baseband due to the TXCO?

L5 frequency = 1176.45MHz

I dont quite understand this question, help pls. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework problem. Please tell us as much as you can about what you **do** understand about the question, show us all of the work you have done so far, and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the TCXO is driving a direct downconverter (quadrature demodulator). Since the carrier is at 1176.45 MHz and the TCXO has a 10 MHz output, the TCXO output is most certainly being used as the reference for a frequency synthesizer such as a phase-locked loop (PLL) - otherwise, the problem would not make sense.

Presumably, the PLL is configured to output the exact carrier frequency (1176.45 MHz). Since the PLL is referenced to the 10 MHz TCXO, the frequency error of 10 ppm propagates through. Thus, our local oscillator frequency range is:

$$1176.45\textrm{ MHz}\pm 10\textrm{ ppm}=1176.45\textrm{ MHz}\pm(10\times 10^{-6}\times 1176.45\textrm{ MHz})$$
$$ = 1176.45\textrm{ MHz}\pm 11.8\textrm{ kHz}$$

Since our local oscillator can be off by up to 11.8 kHz, this means that the carrier will appear shifted in the quadrature baseband by up to 11.8 kHz in either direction. Assuming that the 1176.45 MHz signal is not already offset due to frequency error from the transmitter or Doppler shift, we would expect to see the received carrier offset by up to 11.8 kHz (positive or negative) in baseband.

Comment: Why is it 10*10^-6?

Comment: 10 ppm is 10 parts per million. One part per million is 1/(1 000 000), or 10^-6. So, 10 parts per million is 10*10^-6.

Comment: Cheers Peter. Thanks for the help!